# Is it possible to link Google cloud APIs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-translate, google-speech-api

I am working on a project where I want to stream audio to gclouds speech-to-text API and directly translate it using the translate API. Is it possible to link these two services to reduce latency?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Google has a new product offering on Google Cloud Platform that is immediately available in beta.  It is called Media Translation and can be read about here:

https://cloud.google.com/media-translation

From the first documentation page we read:

> Media Translation translates an audio file or stream of speech into text of another language.

See: https://cloud.google.com/translate/media/docs/streaming